# Best java 3D pie chart API

Tags: java, charts, pie-chart

Which is the best java 3D pie chart API available to use in a standalone java application?  The pie chart should also support detached property.

Answer (score 2):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is the defacto standard

Comment: Agreed. The only problem with JFreeChart is its weight: 1MB!

Answer (score 1):

jchart

http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/samples/pie3d.html